# InnoDB storage for multiple BIT(M) columns?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Let's say if I have a table with four `BIT(1)` columns. Will InnoDB use 4 bytes to store these columns, or will it be smart and use 1 byte?

(Referring to MySQL 8, if it matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that has nothing to do with smart 4 columns are 4 columns. so it woud use 4 byte

Save your bit patterns as Integer.

Depending what you need you can use tinyint 1 Byte (8bits) till BIGINT 8 Byte (64 bits)

If you have or want to save space, you have no better solution.

if you want to store more bit you have to switch to BLOB and use that

For example

- 2 is 00000010
- 3 is 00000011

Any language can transform an integer too a byte array and back again

Answer (score 1):

Do the math.  What percentage of the table size is 3 bytes (4 bytes vs 4 bits)?

I have a Rule of Thumb:  If a suggested improvement (in speed or space) does not help by more than 10%, put it aside and look for something more impactful to focus on.

I assume you are talking about 4 non-NULL Boolean flags?  If you are talking about large bitstrings, the MySQL 8 does handle bit operations for `BLOB`, not just `BIGINT`.

Comment: That's a good rule of thumb. Saving 3 bytes may not make much difference. Was just wondering in terms of theory. I was talking about the `BIT(M)` field type, not boolean flags.

Comment: @osman - Oops, sometimes I misread the question.  I _think_ `BIT(M)` is implemented with `ceil(M/8)` bytes (1 byte in your example).  It's one of the gray areas where I hesitate to say for sure.  Wait!  The title says one thing (bit(M)), the question says another (4 bit(1) _columns_).  I think the latter will be 4 1-byte items.